# SVN checkout failing with the protocol svn+ssh

Tags: svn, powerbuilder, agent

I am using PowerBuilder 12.5 with build 2511.
I am using Agent SVN to connect to the remote svn server.
The server path is like "svn+ssh://user@domain/project/trunk".
Here my problem is i am unable to checkout files from server, but i am able to check in files into server.
while check outing it's giving the error checkout failed. 
can any body help what's the problem while i am check outing files from server?

I am able to checkout files from Power Builder with local SVN repository with ‘file://’ protocol. But i am unable to checkout files from remote SVN server with ‘svn+ssh://’ protocol.

This is the Power Builder log file when i am checking out a file from server

------------------------------------start------------------------------

Checking out selected items...
Agent SVN Info: 
Agent SVN Info: SccCheckout

Agent SVN Info: *   Command: svn.exe --non-interactive --show-updates --verbose status w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: * Directory: C:\Workspace\

Agent SVN : Process started.

Agent SVN : Process running....

Agent SVN Info: 16752    16456 suresh.vadlamudi w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: Status against revision:  16753

Agent SVN : Process completed with exit code: 0

Agent SVN Info: Result: 0

Agent SVN Info: *   Command: svn.exe --non-interactive lock w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: * Directory: C:\Workspace

Agent SVN : Process started.

Agent SVN : Process running....

Agent SVN Info: 'w_login.srw' locked by user 'suresh.vadlamudi'.

Agent SVN : Process completed with exit code: 0

Agent SVN Info: Result: 0

Agent SVN Info: SccFileApplyLock: False

Agent SVN Info:

Agent SVN Info: SccQueryInfo

Agent SVN Info: *   Command: svn.exe --non-interactive --verbose status w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: * Directory: C:\Workspace\

Agent SVN : Process started.

Agent SVN : Process running....

Agent SVN Info: *   Command: svn.exe --non-interactive info C:\Workspace\w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: * Directory:

Agent SVN : Process started.

Agent SVN : Process running....

Agent SVN Info: Path: w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: Name: w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: Working Copy Root Path: C:\Workspace

Agent SVN Info: URL: svn+ssh://user@domain/code/svnrep/project/trunk/w_login.srw

Agent SVN Info: Repository Root: svn+ssh://user@domain/code/svnrep

Agent SVN Info: Repository UUID: cea4ba45-7404-0410-9282-c9295b884410

Agent SVN Info: Revision: 16752

Agent SVN Info: Node Kind: file

Agent SVN Info: Schedule: normal

Agent SVN Info: Last Changed Author: suresh.vadlamudi

Agent SVN Info: Last Changed Rev: 16456

Agent SVN Info: Last Changed Date: 2012-10-08 06:46:05 -0700 (Mon, 08 Oct 2012)

Agent SVN Info: Text Last Updated: 2012-10-08 22:12:26 -0700 (Mon, 08 Oct 2012)

Agent SVN Info: Checksum: 51183433912df60b7ac03afc5eb7111c41783af8

Agent SVN Info: Lock Token: opaquelocktoken:b9ab6225-9234-4c95-8955-a9f9f18f2972

Agent SVN Info: Lock Owner: suresh.vadlamudi

Agent SVN Info: Lock Created: 2012-10-08 22:13:31 -0700 (Mon, 08 Oct 2012)

Agent SVN Info:

Agent SVN : Process completed with exit code: 0

Agent SVN Info: Result: 0

Agent SVN Info: K       16752    16456 suresh.vadlamudi w_login.srw

Agent SVN : Process completed with exit code: 0

Agent SVN Info: Result: 0

Agent SVN Status: File: 'w_login.srw'  Status: 15

SccCheckout for C:\Workspace\w_login.srw appears to have failed.

Operation Completed

--------------------------------------end-------------------------------------------

Comment: Please copy & paste the *full* error message you get when checking out. There are many reasons why you can get "checkout failed" but only one will be applicable to your situation.

Comment: The latest version of Agent SVN has been updated to better hand https:// authentication. That should hopefully fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to checkout the whole source with a GUI for SVN (for example: [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) )

If you can do this, then the problem is with your Agent SVN for PB.

As an alternative you can try PBSCC proxy, which is a good SVN client for PowerBuilder too. We've been using it for 4 years from PB 10 - till the most recent version PB 12.5.1 with the latest build without any major bug. This can be downloaded from [here](http://dm.char.com.ua/pb/pbscc/pbscc.htm).

And this solution is free :)

I hope it helps! Have a nice day!

Br.: Gábor

Comment: I am able to checkout files from Power Builder with local SVN repository with ‘file://’ protocol. The problem is with ‘svn+ssh://’ protocol only.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of *Agent SVN*. Generally when the plug-in works in file mode but does not work in server mode the problem will be a permissioning error.

If you refer to the [Power Builder](http://zeusedit.com/agent/pb/classic.html) setup you will notice in the *Power Builder Workspace* setup you need to provide a user ID.

This is the user ID used to connect to the SVN server so you need to make sure this user ID is correct and is also correctly configured on the server.

Finally the latest version of *Agent SVN* (Version 2.25 or better) does a better job of flagging user ID issues make sure you are running this version.